# Accessing Class Variables inside Module methods

Tags: ruby

Given the following:

```
module RESTable
  BASE_URL  = "http://url.domain/api/rest"
  LOGIN_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/login"
  LOGOUT_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/logout"

  def request_url
    "#{BASE_URL}/mbo/#{@@object_resource}/_format=json"
  rescue NameError
    p "@@object_resource was not defined"
  end
end

class ServiceRequests
  include RESTable
  @@object_resource = "sr"

  def initialize
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

In the pry session, calling request_url yields:

```
"@@object_resource was not defined"
```

but @@object_resource is set as "sr".

The idea is that for each class, I would just include the RESTable module and calling request_url would give me the proper URL based on the @@object_resource of the class I'm including from.

More generally, how can I call the class variable from within the module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by declaring the @@object_resource on the module then raise an error if the @@object_resource was unchanged (i.e. blank).

Here's the updated module:

```
module RESTable
  BASE_URL  = "http://url.domain/api/rest"
  LOGIN_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/login"
  LOGOUT_URL = "#{BASE_URL}/logout"
  @@object_resource = ""

  def request_url
    raise StandardError, "@@object_resource can't be blank" if @@object_resource == ""
    "#{BASE_URL}/mbo/#{@@object_resource}/_format=json"
  rescue NameError
    p "@@object_resource was not defined"
  end
end
```